# What does the word 「っぷち」 mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

Here is the sentence including the word.

> 計画{けいかく}の一!
>
> それは この広{ひろ}い川{かわ}**っぷち**の両{りょう}岸{がん}一[帯]{たい}の おとなも子{こ}どももあそべるでっかい遊{ゆう}園{えん}地{ち}を作{つく}ること!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "dictionary" word is 「[縁]{ふち}」, meaning "side", "edge", "brink", etc.  「**っぷち**」 is its colloquial pronunciation.

「川っぷち」 = "a river bank"

The most common word containing 「っぷち」 would be 「[崖]{がけ}っぷち」, which means "edge of a cliff" literally and "critical point" figuratively.